# Does mlflow support to save model to .h5?

Tags: keras, mlflow

I can input my Keras data (model, kappa, loss, epoch, ...) into MLflow now.
My original model is H5, but the model saved in MLflow under artifacts/model/data/model/saved_model.pb is PB.
Is it possible to save .h5 in MLflow?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

By default mlflow save_format is tf which will allow the model to save in pb format.
I made it work(changing to h5 format) using below code

```
mlflow.tensorflow.log_model(model, "models", keras_model_kwargs={"save_format": "h5"})
```

After this save format will change to h5
[image]

and the model will be saved in model.h5

[image]

Tested this in mlflow v2.3.0

Answer (score 0):

You can save and log a model along with its parameters and metrics. Both preserve the Keras HDF5 format, as noted in [MLflow Keras documentation](https://mlflow.org/docs/latest/models.html#keras-keras).

Comment: I try to add `mlflow.tensorflow.log_model(model=model, artifact_path="model")`, but it show exception. But I cannot find an option to set the model type, can you advise? `mlflow.exceptions.MlflowException: Unknown model type: <class 'src.model.unet.Unet'>`